# 1st or 2nd order of differencing

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, differencing

I have time series and I want to apply differencing to them. However I am not sure whether I should use 1st or 2nd order differencing. In this website ([https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/arimrule.htm](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/arimrule.htm)) it states that if the lag-1 autocorrelation is zero or negative, or the autocorrelations are all small and patternless, then the series does not need a higher order of differencing. If the lag-1 autocorrelation is -0.5 or more negative, the series may be overdifferenced However, in some resources it states that if ACF plot has negative autocorrelation at lag-1 it indicates overdifferencing. These are my ACF plots:
[image]

[image]

Based on these which order of differencing should I use and why?

Comment: In finance, it is common to difference stock prices (raw or often logarithmic) once as they are believed to have a single unit root.

Comment: You should link to your other post with this same plots!